# How to view navigation with infinit sub entries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3.1, navigation

Ive got a simple Model called Category. The model is has three fields : `name:string`, `parent_id:integer` and of cause an `id`! The `parent_id` is an self referential association:

```
has_many :children, :class_name => 'Category', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Category', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
```

So every Category can have subcategories and on and on and on,... This isnt a problem at the database but when it comes to the view Im getting confused!

I dont get how I can loop through each categories `children` and those childrens children,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you had a partial called category you could do something like this

```
%h2= category.name
%ul
  - category.children.each do |child|
    %li
      = render :partial => 'category', :object => child
```

I've used haml but it would be about the same in erb.

Comment: so its possible to call a partial to render itself?^^

Comment: Why not try it and find out :-)