# Display navigation with infinite sub-entries in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, navigation

I have a Model `Category` which has `name:string categoryId:integer parent_id:integer` the `categoryId` doesnt matter in this case I know that it doesnt match the RoR naming convention but I have good reasons for this... Model looks like this:

```
has_many :children, :class_name => 'Category', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Category', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
....
...
..
scope :top_categories, where("parent_id IS NULL")
```

I had a similar problem with the view [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858659/how-to-view-navigation-with-infinit-sub-entries) and this works well but now i need a dropdown with all the categories displayed in its hierarchie. This is really messing with me i simply dont get it! I want the top categories including the children and the children should include her children,... How can I display this in an array?

I need these data for a `collection_select` which should display the whole navigation but not on one area I want to display it like this:

```
Top-Category1
---Sub-Category1
------Sub-Category1-1
------Sub-Category1-2
---Sub-Category2
Top-Category2
---Sub-Category1
```

Can anyone help me?

// Solved it like this:

```
  def self.recursive_categories(categories, prefix='')
            c = []
            categories.collect do |cat|
                    current = Struct::Category.new
                    current.id = cat.id
                    current.name =  "#{prefix}#{cat.name}"
                    c << current
                    if cat.children
                           c += recursive_categories( cat.children, prefix + '--' )
                    end
            end
            c
  end
```

I defined `Struct::Category` in ApplicationHelper which is included in ApplicationController. Then I used this to display it in form:

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.recursive_categories(Category.top_categories), :id, :name %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly simple recursion to get the choices array ready for `select`:

```
# in a helper
def recursive_options categories, prefix=''
  c = []
  categories.collect do |cat|
    c << [ prefix + cat.name, cat.id ]
    if cat.categories
      c += recursive_options( cat.categories, prefix + '--' )
    end
  end
  c
end

# then in your view somewhere
<%= f.select :category_id, recursive_options( Category.top_categories )
```

Comment: I had to mod this a bit because I want to use collection select and this cant deal with `Array` or `Hash` in a nice way so I used `Struct` instead. See Post edit,... but basicly your answer helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This will display all categories as links

```
module CategoriesHelper
  def render_categories(categories, level = 1)
    buffer = ""
    categories.each do |category|
      buffer +=link_to category.name, "#"
      buffer +="<br/>"
      unless category.sub_categories.blank?
        buffer +="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"*level
        buffer +=render_categories(category.sub_categories, level+=1)
      end
    end
    return buffer
  end
end
```

in your view

```
<%= render_categories(Category.top_level).html_safe %>
```

If you want it in select form, here is a link post how to do it, I googled it, didn't try it myself.
http://www.rabbitcreative.com/2008/02/01/turn-an-acts_as_tree-structure-into-a-select-drop-down/